# Cannot read property of "amount" from the request body

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, rest, aws-lambda

I am building REST APIs in Nodejs using AWS. I am expecting a response on Postman saying that the
"

```
Your Bid Must Be Higher than ${auction.highestBid.amount}
```

"
But instead, I get an Internal Server Error on Postman and the error on AWS Cloudwatch looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocZYE.png).
However, I am sending a request on Postman as:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwfdE.png)
Please help!!

I am Expecting the response as:
Your bid must be higher than

```
${auction.highestBid.amount}
```

The patch request body looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COK0N.png)
While the create Request looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7RUk.png)

//placeBid.js

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const createError = require('http-errors');
const {getAuctionById} = require('./getAuction');

const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
async function placeBid(req) {

  const { id } = req.pathParameters;
  const { amount } = JSON.parse(req.body);
  const auction = getAuctionById(id);
  if(amount <= auction.highestBid.amount)
  throw new createError.Forbidden(`Your Bid Must Be Higher than ${auction.highestBid.amount}`);

  const params = {
    TableName: 'AuctionsTable',
    Key : {id},
    UpdateExpression : 'set highestBid.amount = :amount',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':amount' : amount
    },
    ReturnValues : 'ALL_NEW'
  }

  let updatedAuction;
  try {
    const result = await dynamodb.update(params).promise();
    updatedAuction = result.Attributes;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new createError.InternalServerError(error);
  }


  return{
    statusCode : 200,
    body : JSON.stringify(updatedAuction)
  }
}

module.exports.handler = placeBid;
```

//getAuction.js

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    const createError = require('http-errors');
    
    const dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    
    module.exports.getAuctionById = async(id) => {
      let auction;
      try {
        const result = await dynamodb.get({
          TableName : 'AuctionsTable',
          Key : {id}
        }).promise()
        auction = result.Item;
    
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw new createError.InternalServerError(error);
      }
      if(!auction){
        throw new createError.NotFound(`Auction with ID ${id} not found`);
      }
      return auction;
    }
    
    async function getAuction(req) {
      const { id } = req.pathParameters;
      const auction = await getAuctionById(id);
      return{
        statusCode : 200,
        body : JSON.stringify(auction)
      }
    }
    
    module.exports.handler = getAuction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getAuctionById` is `async`. It returns a `Promise`. You have to `await` it before using its value:

```
const auction = await getAuctionById(id);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response but I guess I already did that by writing await dynamodb.get, unless of course, there is some other way to write it.

Comment: You didn't understand. `auction` (in `placeBid`) contains a `Promise`. A `Promise` doesn't have a `highestBid` property.

Comment: Hey thank u so much!! It actually worked as expected !! Thanku so much for saving my day bro :))

Answer (score 2):

You're throwing an error without catching it
`` throw new createError.Forbidden(`Your Bid Must Be Higher than ${auction.highestBid.amount}`); ``, so your Lambda crashes and returns 500 error. That's expected behavior.

Just return a valid response instead

```
return {
    statusCode : 400,
    body : `Your Bid Must Be Higher than ${auction.highestBid.amount}`
  }
```

Comment: Hey Hi! Thank you for answering the question and giving your time for this. I did the aforementioned changes but it still gives an Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see an example of writing a REST API that uses the **AWS SDK for JavaScript (v3**) that can invoke AWS Services and return data, see this example in the **AWS Code Catelog**. Once you successfully build the REST API, you can use Postman to sent requests and view the responses.

This example performs these tasks:

- Integrate a React.js web application with AWS services.The React app uses the Rest API (you can also use Postman to view the responses)
- List, add, and update items in an Aurora table.
- Send an email report of filtered work items by using Amazon SES.
- Deploy and manage example resources with the included AWS CloudFormation script.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/aurora_example_cross_RDSDataTracker_section.html